# optimising the below stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have the below stored procedure and this is basically a stored procedure which do a table clean up based on the views refresh date now my concern is that my stored procedure is working perfectly but as 
a develoer i am more focus on optminzing and not using incorrect synta ,

so request you folks , to please advise and guid if in below stored procedre i am using any incorrect syntax or how can i optimise he below stored prcedure , please advise as i am more concered in optimising and efficitent please advise.

```
create or replace procedure TABLE_CLEAN_UPABLE_CLEAN_UP
is
v_last_cleanup_time timestamp(6);
v_last_mv_refresh_time timestamp(6);
v_last_mv0_refresh_time timestamp(6);
outcome VARCHAR2(100);
i NUMBER := 0;
begin


Select LAST_START_DATE+LAST_RUN_DURATION into v_last_cleanup_time from USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS 
where JOB_NAME='DELTA_TABLE_CLEAN_UP_JOB';     

SELECT count(*) into i  FROM all_mviews WHERE owner = 'XP_TM_TO' AND 
mview_name in ('CASHFLOW_VIEW', 'CASHFLOW_VIEW_0') and LAST_REFRESH_TYPE='COMPLETE'
and CAST(LAST_REFRESH_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) > v_last_cleanup_time;


if i=2 then

SELECT CAST(LAST_REFRESH_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) into v_last_mv_refresh_time FROM all_mviews WHERE owner = 'XP_TM_TO' AND mview_name = 'CASHFLOW_VIEW' and LAST_REFRESH_TYPE='COMPLETE';
SELECT CAST(LAST_REFRESH_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) into v_last_mv0_refresh_time FROM all_mviews WHERE owner = 'XP_TM_TO' AND mview_name = 'CASHFLOW_VIEW_0' and LAST_REFRESH_TYPE='COMPLETE';

delete CASHFLOW_DELTA  where (TRADE_ID,SOURCE_SYSTEM,TRADE_VERSION)
  NOT in 
         (select table1.TRADE_ID,table1.SOURCE_SYSTEM,table1.TRADE_VERSION from CASHFLOW_DELTA table1 
                 INNER JOIN (select TRADE_ID,SOURCE_SYSTEM,max(TRADE_VERSION) as MAX_TRADE_VERSION 
                 from CASHFLOW_DELTA GROUP BY TRADE_ID, SOURCE_SYSTEM) table2
                on table1.TRADE_ID=table2.TRADE_ID
                where table1.SOURCE_SYSTEM=table2.SOURCE_SYSTEM
                and table1.TRADE_VERSION=table2.MAX_TRADE_VERSION
                and table1.BROKERAGE_REALISED='YES')
                and createddate<v_last_mv_refresh_time
                and createddate<v_last_mv0_refresh_time;

end if;         
end;
/
```

Comment: Hi, i would close up the 3 all_mviews to 1 query with case when's in the select clause, then you dont need to use the 2 selects in the IF

Comment: if its working fine then there is no question of incorrect syntax. Oracle doesnot allow wrong Syntax code to execute. :-)

Comment: Thomas  ,Thanks for your valuable advise , i really appreciate it , request you to please showa bit so thatyi can grasp more

Comment: You could try laying the code out neatly ;)

Comment: Thanks william , request you to please advise , i want to mininse the loop also

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLE_CLEAN_UPABLE_CLEAN_UP
IS
   v_last_mv_refresh_time    TIMESTAMP (6);
   i                         NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   SELECT MIN(CAST (LAST_REFRESH_DATE AS TIMESTAMP)), COUNT (*)
     INTO v_last_mv_refresh_time,i
     FROM all_mviews
    WHERE owner = 'XP_TM_TO' 
      AND mview_name IN ('CASHFLOW_VIEW', 'CASHFLOW_VIEW_0') 
      AND LAST_REFRESH_TYPE = 'COMPLETE' 
      AND CAST (LAST_REFRESH_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) > (SELECT LAST_START_DATE + LAST_RUN_DURATION FROM USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS WHERE JOB_NAME = 'DELTA_TABLE_CLEAN_UP_JOB');


   IF i = 2 THEN
      DELETE CASHFLOW_DELTA
       WHERE ((TRADE_ID, SOURCE_SYSTEM, TRADE_VERSION) NOT IN ( SELECT TRADE_ID, SOURCE_SYSTEM, MAX (TRADE_VERSION) AS MAX_TRADE_VERSION
                                                                  FROM CASHFLOW_DELTA
                                                                GROUP BY TRADE_ID, SOURCE_SYSTEM)
               OR NVL(BROKERAGE_REALISED,'NO') <> 'YES')
         AND createddate < v_last_mv_refresh_time;
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Motor's for your efforts also please advise you have minimise  the loop condition Thanks in advance

Comment: For this should know what does mean BROKERAGE_REALISED = 'YES'

Comment: CASFLOW_VIEW uses CASHFLOW_DELTA? Or DELTA_TABLE_CLEAN_UP_JOB uses it?

Comment: Delta_Table_clean_job uses it

Comment: Brokerage_reliease true is just an parameter check

Comment: Changed. Why not do the cleaning in the job? Or this procedure is called inside this job?

Comment: This procedure is called inside job

Comment: Main concern is how can I optimize it and also if my mv that is views not get refreshed then I should log that as exception